# Show new result each time I visit the page

Tags: views

I want to display a result in a view, and each time I visit the page, the result will be the next node from the choosen contenttype.

Is this something I can manage in views or is there any other way?

Comment: "each time I visit the page, the result will be the next node from the choosen content type" - what happens if another user visits the page during that time, what do you see then?

Answer (score 1):

In Views **Sort criteria** Section Choose the **Global** and then choose **Global: Random** field, it will display each time different result(when the page is refreshed) but it will be random.

I hope it will help you.

Comment: This is almost what I want to achive. I skipped this "random" thing cause it has to be shown like 1, 2, 3.

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell you need to create a view with a contextual filters "nid".

then in your custom module you should implement [hook_node_view()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7)
and inside this hook you should [set a variable](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/variable_set/7) after incremental.

then you would need something like [views embed view](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_embed_view/7) to send the variable to the view and get your result.

let me know how it goes.

Comment: Well, all I use is views, no custom module. And I'm not a "pro" drupal user so I don't know how to use all drupal hooks etc.

Comment: take a look at the [Serial] (http://drupal.org/project/serial) it may come in handy.